# MySQL Trigger files Odd Request

Tags: mysql, triggers

Ok you've probably never heard this one before.

I want to manually add the two MySQL trigger files "ins_trig.TRN" and "eventlog.TRG" and have them used in MySQL.

Now, it works when I add them to the /var/lib/mysql/databasename/ directory but it makes me restart MySQL for it to recognize the trigger.

I want to do this without MySQL - is it possible?

No I can't log into MySQL and restart it or manually make the trigger in MySQL. Only writing files can I control it

I KNOW IT'S ODD ALL HELP APPRECIATED! haha ;)

Comment: You're right - i have never heard this one before :P

Comment: Ha, I didn't think anyone would! It's for a security exploit I'm writing

Comment: TRG files contain a list of triggers and are surely read on DBMS start (looking for consistency between inf_schema and actual files). Can't think a way of getting them read without restarting engine.

Comment: Alfabrave I appreciate your help anyways!

Comment: Can you log into MySQL at all? (BTW: Trying to imagine what kind of a weird setup lets you write to the data directory, but not log in to the server)

Comment: No. I can however send queries to the server. I'm doing a MySQL injection attack on a VMware setup and I'm trying to create this trigger file by simply writing these files manually.

Comment: I haven't tested it (or RTFS), but its possible if you open enough other tables, you can cause the table you're interested to be flushed from the cache. Then maybe MySQL will reload the metadata. (Create a bunch of tables with injection if possible) Alternatively, 'flush tables' might do it, if you can inject that.

Comment: It's quite possible a process signal (`SIGALRM`? `SIGHUP`?) might cause mysqld to read its data files again; [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/server-signal-response.html) doesn't mention it however, so it'd be a case of RTFS or trial & error.

Comment: Are you saying to just make a bunch of tables in order to crash it? By the same token do you think overloading MySQL with requests would crash it?

Comment: No, MySQL keeps a certain number of table files open, and cached in memory. This is an LRU cache, when it fills up, the least recently used is removed from the cache. So, depending on how that works, MySQL may re-read all the metadata (including triggers) when it next reads the table. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/table-cache.html

Comment: Interesting - I'll try this and report back!